# CSS3 fadeIn transistion not functioning on iOS devices

Tags: ios, css, css-animations

Trying to get the following, which seems to work on the desktop, to also work on mobile devices, but all I see is white. So the fade in never occurs. Here's my HTML:

```
<a href="https://thecleverroot.com/meet-your-makers-hudson-valley-foie-gras/" title="Folio: Meet Your Makers" class="feature-link">
<section class="feature fade-in one" style="background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) ), url(https://thecleverroot.com/wp-content/uploads/header-hudson-valley-foie-gras.jpg ) no-repeat top center!important; background-size: cover!important;">
<section class="feature-caption"><p class="category-link">Growers</p><h2>Folio: Meet Your Makers </h2><p>Jenny Chamberlain, Chef of Product Development for Hudson Valley Foie Gras, Ferndale, NY</p><p class="read-more">Read</p></section></section>
</a>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.fade-in.one { -webkit-animation-delay: 1.25s; -moz-animation-delay: 1.25s; -o-animation-delay: 1.25s; animation-delay: 1.25s; }
.fade-in { opacity: 0; -webkit-animation: 1s ease-in 0s normal forwards 1 running fadeIn; -moz-animation: 1s ease-in 0s normal forwards 1 running fadeIn; -o-animation: 1s ease-in 0s normal forwards 1 running fadeIn; animation: 1s ease-in 0s normal forwards 1 running fadeIn; }
 body.home a.feature-link { text-decoration: none; }
.feature-caption h2 { font-size: 64px; line-height: .75em; margin: .25em 0; }
.category-link {
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    min-width: 90px;
    height: 31px;
    line-height: 31px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojZXNy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code on CodePen but it does not work on desktop either (I tested the latest Chrome and Safari on Mac OS Yosemite).

If you want to fade in the content of your HTML page after it is being loaded you can do it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .faded-out {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            .fade-in {
                opacity: 1;
                transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
                -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
                -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
            }
            #fadeInContainer {
                background: url(https://thecleverroot.com/wp-content/uploads/header-hudson-valley-foie-gras.jpg);
                padding: 60px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById("fadeInContainer1").className = "fade-in";
                document.getElementById("fadeInContainer2").className = "fade-in"
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="https://thecleverroot.com/meet-your-makers-hudson-valley-foie-gras/" title="Folio: Meet Your Makers" class="feature-link">
            <section id="fadeInContainer1" class="faded-out">
                <h1>Content 1</h1>
            </section>
            <section id="fadeInContainer2" class="faded-out">
                <h1>Content2</h1>
            </section>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

There are 2 CSS classes: `.faded-out` (hides the content while the page is being loaded) and `fade-in` (fades in the content).

Initially the content has the `faded-out` class. When the page is loaded we switch the CSS class to `fade-in` to fade in the content. That is done via javascript.

**EDIT**: I fade in two sections now, as requested in your comment

Comment: I don't want to fade in the entire page. Just certain div's / sections that link to articles (it's a news site).

Comment: You can do that the same way. Just give each section a unique id and the 'faded-out' class and change the CSS class to "fade-in" on each of the sections as described in my answer.

Comment: I updated my answer, so that there are now 2 sections that fade in

Comment: Seems to have worked. Have to do some reformatting of the styles (bit messed up now, but expected). Just a shame it has to be incorporating ID's instead of just classes.

Comment: You could use `document.getElementsByClassName("faded-out")` instead and then iterate over the elements, but getting the elements by their ids is more reliable.